# Can we [replay] the retagging process

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [replay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replay):

- has no tag wiki
- has no tag wiki excerpt
- has 79 questions
- has gotten 4 questions past 30 days
- has gotten 2 questions past 7 days
- has 0 followers
- **Is used for multiple categories that have nothing to do with each other**

### Top questions & catagories (+2 and higher)

- **Creating, replaying and extracting information from/to recordings**

  - [[+7] How do I look into a starcraft 2 replay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853594)
  - [[+4] Record and replay javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093961)
  - [[+3] Replay mouse movement with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130473)
  - [[+3] Getting specific metrics from StarCraft 2 Replays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389594)
- **Security related replay attacks**

  - [[+5] How does Oauth 2 prevent replay attacks in mobile applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198211)
  - [[+3] how to avoid replay attack without using time-stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279777)
  - [[+2] Wicket link replay attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125885)
- **Replay system for messages from a queue**

  - [[+5] Rabbitmq- Designing a message replay service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645842)
  - [[+2] Event sourcing and logging/replaying commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374119)
- **Mirroring databases**

  - [[+2] Maintaining mirrored database of a MongoDB replica set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522500)
- **Macro's**

  - [[+2] How can I record and replay macros in Eclipse 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623214)
- **Simple echo server**

  - [[+2] Reply by message to sender using Arduino Nano and Sim900 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165328)
- **Replay functionality of fault tolerant systems**

  - [[+2] A Scalable Architecture for Reconstructing events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550925)
- **Sql Server RML Utilities**

  - [[+2] Replaying SQL Server Trace for SqlBulkCopy Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836373)
- **Tracing back errors by logging**

  - [[+2] How to log web errors on Asp.Net as Fiddler Request File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453790)

I am requesting that questions of this tag should be retagged, to [replay-attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replay-attack), [replay-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replay-recording) or nothing depending on the category of the question.